# Infinite energy with water and air balls

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, buoyancy, perpetual-motion

[image]

**Question**: Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Better question for you - why should it work? Where does the (supposedly infinite) energy come from?

Comment: because it would violate the first or second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Because of spelling errors and troll face

Comment: @AramTadevosyan, "Because it would violate Xxxxxx's Law" is never an answer to how/why;  It's only an excuse for _not_ answering.  Scientific laws are not like civil laws:  They don't say "this must happen" or "that must not happen."  Scientific laws are mere facts (i.e., relationships that we have always, so far, observed to be true.)  The second law of thermodynamics is not the reason why the machine won't work:  It merely is the reason why you don't have to find the flaw in the designer's thinking in order to _know_ that it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force that the seal has to keep water from escaping must have the same force as the balloon being pushed upwards at least, this will cause it to stop the balloon from going upwards and no motion will occur.

Comment: Not quite sure how this ties to "keeping the water from escaping", but if the water _is_ kept in the tank when a float enters at the bottom, then the float must displace (i.e., lift) a volume of water equal to its own volume.